# Getting list of pointing devices in Windows (pascal)

Tags: winapi, directx, lazarus, freepascal

I'm using Lazarus/FPC and I'm looking for a way to get a list of pointing devices in Windows - and then ultimately to be able to disable and enable particular devices.

A bit of Googling turned up [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb153253(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN and [this](http://wiki.freepascal.org/FPC_and_DirectX) on the FreePascal wiki.

These look like a good starting point but unfortunately I'm falling at the first hurdle... I can't figure out how to create the `manager` object that is referred to in the example.

The MSDN example is (C#):

```cs
private void PopulatePointers(TreeView tvDevices)
{
    //Add "Pointer Devices" node to TreeView
    TreeNode pointerNode = new TreeNode("Pointer Devices");
    tvInputDevices.Nodes.Add(pointerNode);

    //Populate Attached Mouse/Pointing Devices
    foreach(DeviceInstance di in
        Manager.GetDevices(DeviceClass.Pointer,EnumDevicesFlags.AttachedOnly))
    {

        //Get device name
        TreeNode nameNode = new TreeNode(di.InstanceName);
        nameNode.Tag = di;
        TreeNode guidNode = new TreeNode(
            "Guid = " + di.InstanceGuid);

        //Add nodes
        nameNode.Nodes.Add(guidNode);
        pointerNode.Nodes.Add(nameNode);
    }

}
```

Which I have partially translated to Pascal as:

```pascal
uses windows, DirectInput;

procedure getPointingDevices();
begin
  for pointingDevice in Manager.GetDevices(DeviceType.Keyboard,EnumDevicesFlags.AttachedOnly) do
  begin
    devicesTree.Items.AddChild(devicesTree.Items.TopLvlItems[0],pointingDevice.InstanceName);
    end;

    devicesTree.Items.TopLvlItems[0].Expand(true);
end;
```

and I have included `DirectInput.pas`, `DirectX.inc`, `DXTypes.pas`, `Jedi.inc`, `Xinput.pas` (some of which may not actually be needed, I'll work that out later) in the project.

Obviously I need to create the Manager object to be able to access its methods, but I have no idea how to do that from the documentation I've read so far.

Comment: .net code won't translate to fpx code directly. You'd need to start from a C++ sample and translate that.

Comment: @David Heffernan - where is the .net code in my example? The example on MSDN is C# code, but that just gave me the clue that I'd probably need to use the DirectX `DirectInput` functionality to get to the mouse/pointing devices. The DirectX libraries/units have already been translated for Lazarus/FPC use and those are the modules I've added to my project. The problem I am having is that I do not know how to create or what to create the Manager object as... what object type is Manager?

Comment: Er, C# is a .net language. I think you are going to need to understand things a little better to make headway. You seem to be wishing to convert the code without understanding it. That is unlikely to be fruitful.

Comment: OK, so help me out! As far as I understand the C# code (I have experience in C, C++, Pascal, java, JavaScript and others so the general structure appears to make sense) teh Manager object has a number of methods one of which is the GetDevices method that returns an array of devices. I do not know the object type for Manager or the array elements that GetDevices returns and I can't find definitions in the DirextX libraries I have downloaded - even though DirectInput appears to be the subset of DirectX that I need to use according to MSDN. I also seem to have definitions for DeviceType...

Comment: What's the point of trying to understand the .net code if you don't want to use it? Suppose we work out what that type is. Great. Now, that type doesn't exist in your Pascal code. What now? I think you are asking the wrong question, and I think that you are trying hard not to have to understand this complex field. I can understand that, it just won't get you anywhere. The question you should be asking is how to enumerate devices using DirectInput. A question that I am sure has been asked many times before.

Comment: Hmm. You suggest I should instead be asking how to enumerate devices using DirectInput... did you miss the MSDN link in my question? That link points to an example of "Enumerating Microsoft DirectInput Devices", so I already have an answer to that. The problem I have is that the example seems to be reliant on some other bits of code already being present. I don't need to understand the .net/C# code as I am coding in Pascal, I do, however, need to know what the .net/C# code is doing and how it is interacting with the DirectX libraries. I thought I had that bit worked out...

Comment: ... I have also downloaded the DirectX libraries for FPC and I assumed - maybe wrongly - that those libraries would contain the `Manager` types object definitions so that I can create a manager object. I assumed that those libraries would also contain the manager object type methods such as .GetDevices(). If those assumptions are wrong, then I am probably trying to head down the wrong road anyway, but I believed that the DirectX libraries that I have now added to my project would give me access to the DirectX.DirectInput functionality. I thought that's was libraries were for..

Comment: OK, you don't seem to want to hear what I have to say. That's fine. Good luck.

Comment: You seem to be saying I should learn .net/c# and restart my project in that language - not very helpful in my book. I don't want someone to tell me how to write all of my code (or what language to right it in), I simply want pointers to solve little steps that will help me progress and learn - hence a pretty simple and specific question. If I can figure out -or be helped to figure out- how to integrate the DirectX libs properly & have access to their functions and type definitions I'll be partly on my way. You're clearly not the person to help with that so I don't know why you got involved.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that at all. I did not say that for one minute. I said that the .net code that you have doesn't port directly to fpc. Since you know more about this than I do, and since I clearly am the wrong person to help you, I will leave it alone. But good luck, from one Cumbrian to another.

Comment: Clearly I do not know - otherwise why would I be here asking questions. Maybe you could explain what you mean by 'port directly'? Are you saying that the objects and methods in the .net example don't exist in the fpc version of the libraries (an assumption I have readily admitted could well be wrong) - and if that is the case it would seem that understanding the .net example isn't going to help me anyway. Or maybe you could point out where my assumptions are wrong or what I have misunderstood in my interpretation of the .net example?

Comment: *Are you saying that the objects and methods in the .net example don't exist in the fpc version of the libraries (an assumption I have readily admitted could well be wrong) - and if that is the case it would seem that understanding the .net example isn't going to help me anyway.* That's exactly what I have been saying all along. Anyway, I'm tired of this, and have invested more of my time than I should have done.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the DirectInput [`IDirectInput8`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417799.aspx) COM interface.

To enumerate input devices, obtain the `IDirectInput8` interface using the [`DirectInput8Create()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.directinput8create.aspx) function, and then use its [`EnumDevices()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.idirectinput8.idirectinput8.enumdevices.aspx) or [`EnumDevicesBySemantics()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.idirectinput8.idirectinput8.enumdevicesbysemantics.aspx) method.  For example:

```
uses
  Windows, DirectInput;

function MyEnumCallback(lpddi: LPCDIDEVICEINSTANCE; pvRef: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  Tree: TTreeView;
begin
  Tree := TTreeView(pvRef);
  Tree.Items.AddChild(Tree.Items.TopLvlItems[0], lpddi.tszInstanceName);
end;

procedure getPointingDevices;
var
  DI: IDirectInput8;
begin
  OleCheck(DirectInput8Create(HInstance, DIRECTINPUT_VERSION, IDirectInput8, @DI, nil));
  OleCheck(DI.EnumDevices(DI8DEVCLASS_POINTER, @MyEnumCallback, devicesTree, DIEDFL_ATTACHEDONLY));
  devicesTree.Items.TopLvlItems[0].Expand(true);
end;
```

Comment: Hi Remy, that's an interesting one. A quick read of the linked pages suggests it may get me as far as listing the devices and being able to display their native control forms, but it looks like it is not possible to then disable and enable devices programmatically. I have, however, been looking at http://wiki.freepascal.org/Windows_Programming_Tips - half way down is a unit that seems to do the enumeration and the enabling and disabling.. I'm playing with that at the moment, but your solution does look more lightweight and looks to satisfy my original request.